# Android Background Color XML layout

Tags: android, android-layout, background-color, transparent

I have a `dialog` layout that pops up over a different layout. The `Dialog` layout color is listed as transparent.

What the difference between setting a background color as transparent and not setting a background color at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well
Transparent Background :- its transparent.
Not Colored Background / Dialog :- Automatically the dialog will get the Phone theme and display regard it. if its on HC and above it will display Blue , if its less it will show regarding the default theme of android version .

Answer (score 0):

Two simple points i can tell

1. Setting background as transparent , the background will be transparent as the name suggest.
2. Not setting any background, by default it will take one back ground color which little blackish type.